# How to limit interactions in a remote git repo?

Tags: git, scmmanager

I have a git repo and I want kinda 'lock' it for a while so no one can use (clone/pull/push etc.) it.
But I don't want to delete it. How do I do it?

Comment: Where is your remote repo? Are you using bitbucket, GitHub, or GitLab, or something else?

Comment: @mnestorov we use scm manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could install a [pre-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) on the remote that will always exit with a non-zero exit value, and ideally print some helpful message.

This wouldn't prevent cloning, but since you certainly can't do anything about existing clones anyway, I don't think there's much value in that.

If you want to prevent everything, you'll have to disable it on the transport layer (be it ssh, http or whatever)